# Is there fluff available for the towns in Middenland?

Tags: lore, wfrp-2e

Is there any fluff for the towns in Middenland, like Hargum, Holzbeck, Immelscheld, and so on? I am about to begin running the Ashes of Middenheim series, and I was wanting to add a few things on the journey to Middenheim from Untergard.

Answer (score 5):

Your best starting point is [*Sigmar's Heirs*](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/62849/Warhammer-Fantasy-Roleplay-2nd-Edition-Sigmars-Heirs?affiliate_id=188022). The Empire is detailed within, with gazette entries for each province, in size and population (for equipment availability, etc.), wealth, militia (and quality), and a note or two. For example, Immelscheld, a GM might be able to craft the following gossip or narrative:

> Immelscheid was once a village and is now a ghost-town, reduced to ruins in 2517IC.

The details of its destruction are not provided, unfortunately.

Major land and *dramatis personæ* are also detailed for each province in *Sigmar's Heirs*.

### Before the Storm of Chaos

Continuing with the example of Immelscheid, a quick look at *Warhammer City: Middenheim: City of the White Wolf* provides details on Immelscheid (again "narratively") as follows:

> With a population of 90 and poor (Weath 2), Immelscheid trades in Timber and Slate. It has a watch garrison of six average men and 10 fodder, conscripts at best.

WFRP 1e (First Edition) is generally considered to be set c. 2515IC (2512 is specifically called out in game handouts).

Comment: I'm finding it curious that 1E uses Immelscheid. 2E uses Immelscheld.

Comment: I wrote this answer almost 10 years ago. I would also add [Mad Alfred's WFRP Pages, Maps and Gazettes](https://www.madalfred.com/) as a free starting pointing as well. Much of *Sigmar's Heirs* originates from the work of Alfred Nuñez Jr..